# Local memory usage on OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu

I am looking for bandwidth optimization by local memory usage on OpenCL and it seems that taking a block size multiple of 32 or 16 will be better in terms of performance. However, I have a crucial question: in case we'd like to make Matrix multiplication where the matrix size is not divisible by 32/16 (Local size of each work-group for example), do you know how the kernel function will proceed during the computation phase?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The usual work-around is to zero-pad the matrices to the next multiple of your optimal workgroup size. This tends to be much faster than special-casing edges or using non-power-of-2 workgroup sizes. Is that something you can do in your case?

Comment: @pmdj Thanks for your answer. Is OpenCL 2.0 able to do the automatic zero-pad?

Comment: CL 2.0 allows non-uniform workgroup sizes, but I don't think there's any automatic handling of out-of-range memory buffer access - after all, it's just a sequence of bytes, the "2D" matrix mapping is done in your code. That said, I don't have any 2.0-specific experience with this, so maybe there's some fast path. Personally, I'd probably still just pad everything throughout.